# PHP array, table, form, multiplying... argh

Tags: php

I have tried for hours, and hope you can help me now :

I am trying to get values from a HTML form via `$_POST` into a table via PHP, and multiplying two numbers: `['amount'] * ['price'] = $totalprice`

So far so good.

I get something that might look like this:

Description – Amount – Format – Price – **Total ($totalprice)**

Spoon – 3 – pieces – 4 – **12**

Plate – 2 – pieces – 3 – **6**

Glass – 6 – pieces – 3 – **18**

Now how do I sum up all the `“Total” ($totalprice)’s` 12+6+18 so I get the result: ***36*** ?

The piece of code I’m struggling with:

```
foreach($_POST['description'] as $value)
{
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $i+1;
echo "</td>
<td>".$value."</td>
<td><center>".$_POST['amount'][$i]."</td>
<td><center>".$_POST['format'][$i]."</td>
<td><center>".$_POST['price'][$i]."</td>";

//Figures out the total price = amount * price
$x1 = $_POST['amount'] [$i];
$x2 = $_POST['price'] [$i];
echo "<td><center>";
$totalprice = $x1 * $x2;
echo $totalprice;
//Figures out the total price = amount * price

$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sum all totals while iterating

```
$grand_total = 0;
foreach($_POST['description'] as $value)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    // code here...

    $totalprice = $x1 * $x2;
    echo $totalprice;

    $grand_total = $grand_total + $totalprice;
    $i++;
}
echo $grand_total;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked like a charm.

If I wasn't such a noob in this forum, I would give you a +

Comment: @user3395966 you are welcome man, if you feel my answer was correct and helped you out you might consider accepting it so you will also help people in the future with similar problems. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$totalprice = 0;
foreach($_POST['description'] as $value)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $i+1;
    echo "</td>
    <td>".$value."</td>
    <td><center>".$_POST['amount'][$i]."</td>
    <td><center>".$_POST['format'][$i]."</td>
    <td><center>".$_POST['price'][$i]."</td>";

    //Figures out the total price = amount * price
    $x1 = $_POST['amount'] [$i];
    $x2 = $_POST['price'] [$i];
    echo "<td><center>";
    $totalprice = $totalprice + ($x1 * $x2);
    $i++;
}
echo $totalprice;
```